# Using "$RANDOM" to generate a random string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, random

I am trying to use the Bash variable `$RANDOM` to create a random string that consists of 8 characters from a variable that contains integer and alphanumeric digits, e.g., `var="abcd1234ABCD"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use parameter expansion. `${#chars}` is the number of possible characters, `%` is the modulo operator. `${chars:offset:length}` selects the character(s) at position `offset`, i.e. 0 - length($chars) in our case.

```
chars=abcd1234ABCD
for i in {1..8} ; do
    echo -n "${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}"
done
echo
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't understand the use of the module %, can you or someone explain me why?

Comment: @Dimareal: $RANDOM could be too large. By using modulo, the result can't be greater than the length of the $chars, i.e. you can use it to index a random char.

Comment: Is there a version that works with "ash" and "sh" and not only with bash? I'm working on embedded system running OpenWrt and because or space restraints there is no space for bash. I get this error: # /tmp/rnd.sh
/tmp/rnd.sh: line 5: syntax error: bad substitution

Comment: if `chars` contains escape characters, this can launch the bash command `l`. Try it with `chars='<=>| -,;:!/."()[]{}*\&#%+012345689abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: @MrMartin: No, it doesn't run any command, it just expands a glob. Fixed by double quoting.

Comment: what's the final echo for?

Comment: @Fuseteam: For a newline.

Comment: @choroba ah now i get it thanks, it show no character so it was a bit confusing

Answer (score 24):

For those looking for a random alpha-numeric string in bash:

`LC_ALL=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 64`

The same as a well-documented function:

```sh
function rand-str {
    # Return random alpha-numeric string of given LENGTH
    #
    # Usage: VALUE=$(rand-str $LENGTH)
    #    or: VALUE=$(rand-str)

    local DEFAULT_LENGTH=64
    local LENGTH=${1:-$DEFAULT_LENGTH}

    LC_ALL=C tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c $LENGTH
    # LC_ALL=C: required for Mac OS X - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363194/403075
    # -dc: delete complementary set == delete all except given set
}
```

Comment: _tr: Illegal byte sequence_

Comment: @Sukima please try to add LC_ALL=C before the command and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 13):

**OPTION 1** - Specific length, only lowercase letters, numbers and dashes

`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` OR on macOS just use `uuidgen`

> After generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years,
> the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%. The
> probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on
> earth owns 600 million UUIDs  [source](https://www.liquisearch.com/universally_unique_identifier/random_uuid_probability_of_duplicates)

DEMO: `x=100; while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid; x=$(($x-1)); done`

Examples:

```
be821d3c-c484-41d9-8fc8-eb8bc3683360
ba0b72e2-7969-481e-94c2-7a716c40c3e8
e0183127-a6e3-453b-87cd-7ea912afc49a
0ad84c92-186a-4c4d-aea9-5951083c9ed8
a42e0c6a-4f06-4c32-a289-dd0391f11aba
a82b27d4-9bdb-403d-add4-8a72d36fb864
a16fcd29-02cd-448a-a048-ae6bde3c707c
```

**OPTION 2** - No specific length, no openssl needed, only letters and numbers, slower than *option 3*

```
sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" <<< $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*()-+' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
```

OR on macOS:

```
sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" <<< $(head -c 24 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc '[:print:]' | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*()-+' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
```

DEMO: `x=100; while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" <<< $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*()-+' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1) <<< $(openssl rand -base64 17); x=$(($x-1)); done`

Examples:

```
j0PYAlRI1r8zIoOSyBhh9MTtrhcI6d
nrCaiO35BWWQvHE66PjMLGVJPkZ6GBK
0WUHqiXgxLq0V0mBw2d7uafhZt2s
c1KyNeznHltcRrudYpLtDZIc1
edIUBRfttFHVM6Ru7h73StzDnG
```

**OPTION 3** - No specific length, **openssl** *needed*, only letters and numbers (if used with sed), faster than *option 2*

```
openssl rand -base64 12 # only returns

rand=$(openssl rand -base64 12) # only saves to var

sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" <<< $(openssl rand -base64 17) # leave only letters and numbers
# The last command can go to a var too.
```

DEMO: `x=100; while [ $x -gt 0 ]; do sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g" <<< $(openssl rand -base64 17); x=$(($x-1)); done`

Examples:

```
9FbVwZZRQeZSARCH
9f8869EVaUS2jA7Y
V5TJ541atfSQQwNI
V7tgXaVzmBhciXxS
```

Answer (score 13):

Another way to generate a 32 bytes (for example) hexadecimal string:

```
xxd -l 32 -c 32 -p < /dev/random
```

add `-u` if you want uppercase characters instead.

Answer (score 8):

Not using `$RANDOM`, but worth mentioning.

Using shuf as source of entropy (a.k.a randomness) (which, in turn, may use `/dev/random` as source of entropy. As in `shuf -i1-10 --random-source=/dev/urandom) seems like a solution that use less resources:

```
$ shuf -er -n8  {A..Z} {a..z} {0..9} | paste -sd ""
tf8ZDZ4U
```

Comment: I would like to add that when using using a Makefile, `tr` from `/dev/random` will cause `tr: write error: Broken pipe` errors which this solution avoids. Well done.

Answer (score 5):

```
head -1 <(fold -w 20  <(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom))
```

This is safe to use in bash script if you have safety options turned on:

```
set -eou pipefail
```

This is a workaround of bash exit status 141 when you use pipes

```
tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 20 | head -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *sparse* array to shuffle characters.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

array=()
for i in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do
    array[$RANDOM]=$i
done
printf %s ${array[@]::8} $'\n'
```

(Or alot of random strings)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

b=()
while ((${#b[@]} <= 32768)); do
    a=(); for i in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do a[$RANDOM]=$i; done; b+=(${a[@]})
done
tr -d  ' ' <<< ${b[@]} | fold -w 8 | head -n 4096
```

Answer (score 3):

Little bit obscure but short to write solution is

```
RANDSTR=$(mktemp XXXXX) && rm "$RANDSTR"
```

expecting you have write access to current directory ;-)
`mktemp` is part of coreutils

UPDATE:
As Bazi pointed out in the comment, mktemp can be used without creating the file ;-) so the command can be even shorter.

```
RANDSTR=$(mktemp --dry-run XXXXX)
```

Comment: Good one! Better to use it in dry-run mode so we do not actually create anything. Simply `$(mktemp --dry-run XXXXXXXX)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Why is there it is unsafe?
`-u, --dry-run       do not create anything; merely print a name (unsafe)`
I'll edit my answer to add that variant, thank you Bazi!

Comment: Not that it matters a whole lot but the dry-run flag is a gnu extension and does not exist on BSDs.

Answer (score 2):

An abbreviated safe pipe workaround based on [Radu Gabriel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66223024/16910794) and tested with GNU bash version 4.4.20 and `set -euxo pipefail`:

```
head -c 20 <(tr -dc [:alnum:] < /dev/urandom)
```