# What does this RANDOM-based command mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, random

I'm using the RANDOM variable to generate a string that consists of 8 characters, but I don't fully understand how it works. The structure of the command is `${char:offset:length}`:

```
char="1234abcdABCD"
echo -n ${char:RANDOM%${#char}:8}
```

Can someone explain how it works? Especially `RANDOM%${#char}`?
What do `%` and `#` mean in this case?

Comment: Have tried looking for the `man page` for RANDOM, it's fairly easy and very detailed.

Comment: by searching, i found that the modulo is used so the command can't give something bigger than the lengh. but not sure

Comment: @Kiloreux: The `random(3)` man page is not particularly relevant. This code uses the `$RANDOM` shell variable, a feature of bash.

Comment: I used `:1` in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32484733/1030675

Comment: @KeithThompson it *is* a modulo (specifically a remainder, as the bash manpage refers to it). I agree its position wrt RANDOM makes it look a lot like a parameter trim, but it this position in a substring extraction the syntax is that of arithmetic evaluation nonetheless.

Comment: @JB.: You're absolutely right. I can't edit my previous comment, but I'll post a corrected version and delete the old one.

Comment: @Dimareal: `info bash` and search for the section on "Shell Parameter Expansion", or [read it here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The relevant section is "Substring Expansion". (To correct my earlier comment, which I've just deleted, the `%` *is* a modulo operator; I mistook it for the `${PARAMETER%WORD}` syntax, which has a different meaing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Walk through it step by step:

```
$ echo ${#char}
12
```

This returned the length of the `char` string. It's documented in the `bash` manpage in the "Parameter expansion" section.

```
$ echo $(( RANDOM % 12 ))
11
$ echo $(( RANDOM % 12 ))
7
$ echo $(( RANDOM % 12 ))
3
```

This performs a modulus (`%`) operation on `RANDOM`. `RANDOM` is a `bash` special variable that provides a new random value each time it is read.  `RANDOM` is documented in the "Shell variables" section; modulus in the "Arithmetic evaluation" section.

```
$ echo ${char:0:8}
1234abcd
$ echo ${char:4:8}
abcdABCD
$ echo ${char:8:8}
ABCD
```

This performs substring extraction. It's documented in the "Parameter expansion" section.

Putting it all together:

```
$ echo -n ${char:RANDOM%${#char}:8}
```

This extracts up to 8 characters of the `char` string, starting at a random position in the string.