# Command line "random"? Seedable random binary data for disk testing

Tags: linux, shell, random, benchmarking, glibc

I want to do a quick write test of a SSD (that I bought on ebay).

I want to write a stream of pseudo random data and then read them back and compare.

Something like ("dd" omitted for clarity) :

```
random $seed > /dev/nvme0n1
random $seed | cmp - /dev/nvme0n1
```

... with maybe some flags to control "initstate" and buffer size

Comment: [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) might be useful; my answer generates multiple gigabytes per second of random digits as text, from a hard-coded seed (like 13GB/s on a 2.5GHz Haswell laptop).  If you're looking to test if the SSD does on the fly compression, though, you'd want something that doesn't dilute the entropy into printable ASCII, like just using the output of an xorshift+ generator directly.  If you know C, my code should be easy to modify.

Comment: Or openssl comes with a `rand(1)` command-line program which can take a seed file.

Comment: Wow.  That's blazing fast.  For now, I just did the obvious : random() in a loop : about 400 MB/s, which is similar to the write speed of my $18 SSD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using random to generate a random string in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484504/using-random-to-generate-a-random-string-in-bash)

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need high-quality randomness, running a 4 or 8 copies of a simple PRNG (with different seeds) like xorshift+ in parallel in the SIMD elements of a 32-byte register can approach `memset` speeds for DRAM (a CPU core significantly faster than DRAM in terms of bandwidth, not just latency).

Comment: @PeterO.: That's text data; can it be easily extended to incompressible binary data?  The top answer is very slow even compared to disk speeds, using BASH `$RANDOM` for each byte.  Although you can seed it by assigning to `RANDOM`.  I guess the 2nd answer mentions `openssl rand`.