# How to generate a random string in bash?

Tags: string, bash, random

My goal is to have something like this in bash:

```
str=random_string(n scharacters)
```

I have managed to do the following:

```
chars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ ))
do
   str="${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}"
done
```

The problem is that `str` also contains new lines.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I saw that before but my goal is not to print the string. My goal is to store it in a variable. It may be easy to do but I am completely amateur in bash and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: `My goal is to store it in a variable.` sooo. `variable=$(whatever; while (..); here; done; you want)`?

Comment: There's an *almost* exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32484504/3266847), but the problem here seems to be generating the string, not getting a random character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
n=10

str=
for ((i = 0; i < n; ++i)); do
    str+=${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}
    # alternatively, str=$str${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1} also possible
done

echo "$str"
```

Your code was almost correct, except that you've missed the `+=` operator. The `+=` operator appends to the variable’s (`str` here) previous value. This operator was introduced into `bash` with version 3.1. As an aside note, it can also be applied to an array variable in order to append new elements to the array. It also must be noted that, *in an arithmetic context*, the expression on the right side of the `+=` operator is evaluated as an arithmetic expression and added to the variable’s current value.