# Rename multiple files in Bash with random strings

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, rename

Assuming an arbitrary number of files with random names and the same file extension (e.g., `file1.txt`, `file2.txt...fileN.txt`). How could you rename them all reliably with a random string?

Such as, `file1.txt, file2.txt...fileN.txt` to `asdfwefer.txt, jsdafjk.txt`... or `any combination of letters from latin alphabet].txt`

Comment: Just a simple iteration and rename? Why is complex? What is your attempt?

Comment: @JRichardsz `for file in *.txt; do mv -- "$file" "${file%.txt}[random string].jpg" done` I don't know how to introduce the random string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "$RANDOM" to generate a random string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484504/using-random-to-generate-a-random-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickest hack to get a random-letters string I can think of is

```
head -c24 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc a-zA-Z
```

so

```
randomname() { head -c24 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc a-zA-Z; }
for f in file*.txt; do mv "$f" `randomname`.txt; done
```

and your odds of a collision are down in the one-in-a-billion range even with a huge list. Add a serial number on the end of `randomname`'s output and that goes away too.

Answer (score 1):

These are the algorithm steps:

- iterate files
- get name and extension
- compute a random string
- rename using mv command

**script.sh**

```
location=$1

echo "before"
find $location

for full_file_name in $location/*.*
do
    filename=$(basename -- "$full_file_name")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    new_name=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
    echo "rename from: $filename.$extension to: $new_name.$extension"
    mv $full_file_name "$location/$new_name.$extension"
done

echo "after"
find $location
```

**execution**

```
bash script.sh /tmp/workspace/input
```

**result**

Script was tested and the result of demo files is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbkSA.png)

Comment: A screen shot of the output is less useful than just a copy/paste of the actual text. Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I think this may help the reader believe that the algorithm works because is an image as proof. Also the images prohibition  is commonly for questions, not for the answers and only for source code or error messages. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Images have multiple usability problems which are spelled out in the link I provided. If we really thought you wanted to falsify information in your answer, a forged image is not much harder to produce than forged text.